# Python - Strip each element of a Tuple

Tags: python, tuples, dbf

I am retrieving data from a DBF file and I need to generate a SQL script to load the data into a database. I already have this but the values are stored in a tuple and before i create the SQL script I want to strip each item of the tuple. For example, I am getting this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES('Value 1     ', 'TESTE123', '  ADAD ')
```

And I need to get this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES('Value 1', 'TESTE123', 'ADAD')
```

For that I am trying with this code:

```
with dbf.Table(filename) as table:
            for record in table:
                fields = dbf.field_names(table)
                fields = ','.join(fields)
                place_holders = ','.join(['?'] * len(fields))
                values = tuple(record.strip())
                sql = "insert into %s (%s) values(%s)" & ('my_table', fields, values)
```

And I am getting the following error:
dbf.FieldMissingError: 'STRIP' no such field in table

What do you purpose?

Comment: Is `&` a typo for `%`? Don't create SQL queries like that.

Comment: @dev_community, can you extend the [mre] to show how you're _actually running_ the query? That way we could change the way you're running it to move the data out-of-band from the syntax (using bind parameters, and thus avoiding the security pitfalls one runs into otherwise).

Comment: `values = tuple(s.strip() for s in record)`. But don't build your SQL statements like this. Use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbf.Record` is not a `str`, and doesn't have string methods.

If every field in the record is text (e.g. `Character` or `Memo`, not `Numeric` or `Date`) then you can:

```
values = [v.strip() for v in record]
```